# What are the steps involved for svg button click and copy the url

Tags: automation, karate

Writing steps for UI testing using karate framework
so basically svg button, have to click then the URL in the new tab for further functionality processing
how to handle that ?

i tried below code

- def secure_url = mouse("#root > section > section > main > div > div > div.ant-table-wrapper > div > div > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(7) > span > button > svg").click()

and verified the secure_url value using
print secure_url
it prints com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverMouse@664e5dee
but Expected is URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Karate methods will return an `Element` object on which you have to call more methods. Please spend some time to read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#chaining

```
* def elem = locate('#some-id')
* def url = elem.attribute('href')
```